# Bash loop according to elapsed time?

Tags: bash, time

How can I make a loop in Bash that will run until exactly one minute has passed, then stop and go to the next instruction?

I want to measure time independently of any of the statements in the loop and not measure based on sleeping.

As soon as 1 minute has passed, it would drop everything and go to the next instruction.

How do I do this??

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is inside the loop?

Comment: It sends temperature data to a file which is read through AJAX and sent to Plotly and Google Charts API's

Comment: This is a pretty roundabout way to do it...I was trying to run the script every second with `cron` but cron only does minutes

Comment: WHOA! Describing that just made me think of a better way to do it -- if it loads at startup and runs infinitely, and delays 1 second and 1 second! (until reboot)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. If it's not too hard, you should share your answer with us. :)

Comment: I will -- I'm still working on making it work

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way of doing what I was trying to do -- instead of running the script for a minute, killing it, and restarting it using cron (which was the original goal), I just made an infinite loop in the script, and set it to run at startup.